# how do I enable full text search for large pdfs in cost effective way?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, elasticsearch, full-text-search, amazon-opensearch

I have large number of PDFs (to say around 1 million) and those PDFs varies in their size. They could be from 5 pages top 100 pages long. I want my users to be able to do a text search (a google like input box) and relevant PDF results should come up with the option to view/download the PDF as well. Furthermore these PDFs will keep adding on weekly basis (that number won't be too high maybe around 100-200 PDFs a week)

Currently my application is using Postgres, so just wanted to know what is the best and cost effective way to handle the stated use case. I am using AWS as cloud provider.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Do you want to serch from inside pdf files ?

Comment: That is correct, of course the text from PDFs can be extracted and put into db

Answer (score 2):

There is a perfect fit integration for your use case. [Elasticsearch Workplace search](https://www.elastic.co/enterprise-search/workplace-search).

1. upload all the PDF files into google drive, or dropbox
2. enable the ingestion from google drive to elasticsearch
3. search your data
   It will sync the data between google drive and elasticsearch with a scheduled task e.g. every [2 hours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyrXQ.png).

You can see the supported file types in [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/workplace-search/current/content-sources-content-extraction.html#content-sources-content-extraction-text).

Here is an example search results. You can `view/download` the search results. It also supports index level and field level authentication.

[image]

Comment: I have a couple of inquiries regarding the user interface (UI) of Elastic. I would like to know if it is possible to implement my own UI in my application instead. Additionally, I would like the PDF files to be protected in a way that users can only view them within my app and not download them. Based on the screenshot provided, it does not appear to be possible to add any additional restrictions or security measures. Lastly, I would like to understand how the pricing of this solution compares to other alternatives.

Comment: There will be 100s of GBs PDF so costing is quite important here

Comment: You can check this for prices on elastic cloud.
https://www.elastic.co/pricing

Comment: As far as I know, you can create your own UI. *I would like the PDF files to be protected in a way that users can only view them within my app and not download them.*  **The best way is benchmarking. The good news is you can try for free for 14 days.**